# UIView in UIScrollView does not appear

Tags: ios, uiview, menu, uiscrollview, uibutton

I'm trying to create a horizontally scrollable menu similar to that in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqg94x27Nwo&feature=player_embedded).

For some reason the `UIView` doesn't appear after adding a bunch of `UIButtons` to it and adding it to the `UIScrollView`.  Here's my code (it's called in `-viewDidLoad` of a subclass of `UIViewController`):

```
//set up scrollview
UIScrollView *designPicker = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 431, 320, 49)];

//set up a view to drop into the scroll view
UIView * buttonsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 431, 640, 49)];

//add buttons to scrollview
// load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
NSUInteger i;
float runningX = designPicker.frame.origin.x;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    UIButton *tempBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [tempBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(runningX, designPicker.frame.origin.y, 30.0, 30.0);
    tempBtn.frame = rect;
    [buttonsView addSubview:tempBtn];
    runningX = runningX + 35;
    [tempBtn release];
}

[designPicker setContentSize:buttonsView.frame.size];
[designPicker addSubview:buttonsView];
[self.view addSubview:designPicker];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not add the buttons using the frame of the `UIScrollView`. The origin of the frame is in the superview's (superview of the `UIScrollView`) coordinates. You should make the buttons' frame relative to the `UIView`. So if you want the buttons to appear at the top of the view that you should start at (0,0).

Comment: Thanks for the response Diederik.  The thing is that the buttons' frame IS relative to the UIView since the UIScrollView is a subview of the view.  So, the buttons' frames are relative to superview of the UIScrollView.  Maybe I'm missing something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding scrollview as subview to your view, add view as subview of scrollview. As-

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.view];
// release scrollView as self.view retains it
self.view=self.scrollView;
[self.scrollView release];
```

And make sure your view should have large content size than content size of your scrollview.It worked for me.